# Proving an identity involing the Riemann zeta function

Tags: number-theory, summation, riemann-zeta

I recently read somewhere (but lost the source) that one could express the composite zeta function $C(n)$ using the prime zeta function $P(n)$ and the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(n)$ in the following manner:

$$
C(n)=P(n)\left(\zeta(n)-1\right) - \zeta(n)\sum\frac{1}{p^nq^n},
$$

where $n$ is an integer greater than $1$, and the sum $\sum\frac{1}{p^nq^n}$ is taken over all primes $p$ and $q$, for which $p\neq q$. As usual, here $\zeta(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^n}$.

At first glance this does not even seem to hold (*how does the manipulation of infinite series on the right hand side (multiplication of infinite series) factor
 out all the prime terms?*), however I remember seeing a proof somewhere. Unfortunately I forgot to write it down so now I'm trying to work it out myself.

We can expand the left hand side as:

$$
\sum_p\frac{1}{p^n}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^n} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^n}\sum\frac{1}{p^nq^n},
$$

but I don't see how this results in

$$
\sum_c\frac{1}{c^n},
$$

i.e., the sum over all composite numbers. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\zeta(s) = P(s)+(\zeta(s)-P(s))$.

Comment: On a related matter, maybe of interest. A long while ago I have asked a question on MO about the Composite "Euler" Product: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53266/values-where-infinite-products-of-primes-and-composites-are-equal

Comment: @reuns Thank you for your reply. Could you please elaborate more on your comment?

Comment: ??? Elaborate on what ? Don't you see how $\sum_{n \text{ composite}} n^{-s}$ appears from what I wrote ?

Comment: @reuns It's obvious that $\zeta(s)=P(s)+C(s)$, that was not my question. Using that in the identity above, however, is not obvious. I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on how it can be used to prove the identity in my question.

Comment: The "identity" in your question is  nonsense, because $\zeta(s)=P(s)+C(s)$.

Comment: @reuns So it is not correct? That's what I suspected... However actually I just found the original source (don't have the time to read it yet), it's at: http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-22/NNTDM-22-4-12-15.pdf

Comment: This pdf is a complete nonsense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70427/discussion-between-pickle-and-reuns).

Comment: I don't know. Check it is really "published" and send them an email. For sure formula 13 is a nonsense with $J_2^{(s)} = \sum_{p, q} (pq)^{-s} = P(s)^2$

Comment: Whatever the definition of $J_2^{(s)}$ is, it is a nonsense. Once this is said, I don't really care if it has been published or not, all I can say is you can send an email, and if you want help to explain why it is a nonsense, tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity **does not hold** (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288847/ps-1-sqrt-frac2-zetas-sqrt-frac2-zeta2s-sqrt-frac2-zeta)). Moreover, the [paper that claims this](http://%20nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-22/NNTDM-22-4-12-15.pdf) contains a number of (major) problems.